# Convert a multi-line bash command into a one line command

Tags: linux, bash

I am looking for a program that can convert a multi-line bash command into a one line command.

For example:

```
find . -type d -print0 | while read -d '' -r dir; do
    files=("$dir"/*)
    printf "%5d files in directory %s\n" "${#files[@]}" "$dir"
done
```

could get converted to:

```
find . -type d -print0 | while read -d '' -r dir; do files=("$dir"/*); printf "%5d files in directory %s\n" "${#files[@]}" "$dir"; done
```

If possible, free and works with Linux or Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: If anyone has any idea please add an answer.

Comment: I haven't found anything so far.